# Android studio Electric Eel Render ui issue

Tags: android, kotlin

As I update the version of android studio to Electric Eel, I am getting Render issue like

> Infinite cycle trying to resolve '?textAppearance': Render may not be accurate.

due to this, i am unable to view the xml layout

Xml layout should be visible to see the changes

Here is the screenshot for reference

[image: Here is the screenshot for reference]

Answer (score 0):

Changing

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

in the **build.gradle (Module:App)** file worked for me.